# can not pass user variable in script component

Tags: ssis

I am trying to call 2 user variables for other computations in script component.

```
public string getFinYear(DateTime dt)
    {
        string finYr;
        if (dt.Month >= 7 && dt.Month <= 12)
            finYr = dt.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2) + "_" + dt.AddYears(1).Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2);
            //finYr = dt.Year.ToString()+ "-" + dt.AddYears(1).Year.ToString();

        else
            finYr = dt.AddYears(-1).Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2) + "_" + dt.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2);
            //finYr = dt.AddYears(-1).Year.ToString() + "-" + dt.Year.ToString();

        return finYr; 
    }


public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        Dts.Variables["User::currentDT"].Value = DateTime.Now; // current date time

        if (Dts.Variables.Contains("CalYear") == true && Dts.Variables.Contains("CalMonth") == true)
        {
           int yr = (int)Dts.Variables["CalYear"].Value;

           int mth = (int)Dts.Variables["CalMonth"].Value;

            DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(yr, mth, 1);

            Dts.Variables["User::monthName"].Value = firstDayOfMonth.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            Dts.Variables["User::finYear"].Value = getFinYear(firstDayOfMonth);

        } .....
```

In the above code, I manually set CalYear = 2015 and CalMonth = 2; However when I run the script it returns nothing for monthName and finYear.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check if you have these variables marked as "ReadWrite variables" for the script task.

Comment: thanks, yes i ticked all of them. actually, it is very easy to pass those system variables, but for user variables, it is a bit annoying

Answer (score 0):

try debugging the script task or use message box to show the values before assigning it to day or month.
using System.Windows.Forms;

MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["Foo"].Value.ToString())